# Drupal TWIG rendoring cleanup

Tags: theming

I'm trying to get my head around how twig get rendered out. I just wrapped up working on my first Drupal site, which I really struggled with. So I spun up a local instance, to try somethings out. I install the Paragraphs module and get to work. I created a section component, and a simple title, copy and image one.

How do I get just the HTML i've written, and not all the extra mark up? Is that even possible.

On the last project it was a struggle trying to get Flex to work because of the extra markup.

Thanks guys!

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-12 col-lg-6'>
    <h2>{{ content.field_copy_title }}</h2>
    {{ content.field_text }}
  </div>
  <div class='col-12 col-lg-6'>
    {{ content.field_image}}
  </div>
</div>
```

When I check source, I get this:

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--paragraph--field-component--section.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--field-component.html.twig
   x field--paragraph--section.html.twig
   * field--field-component.html.twig
   * field--entity-reference-revisions.html.twig
   * field.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/bt4ChildTheme/components/text-field/field--paragraph--section.html.twig' -->

      <div data-quickedit-field-id="paragraph/4/field_component/en/default">
              <div>

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'paragraph' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * paragraph--two-column-image-and-copy--default.html.twig
   x paragraph--two-column-image-and-copy.html.twig
   * paragraph--default.html.twig
   * paragraph.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/bt4ChildTheme/components/two-column-image-and-copy/paragraph--two-column-image-and-copy.html.twig' -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
    <h2>

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--paragraph--field-copy-title--two-column-image-and-copy.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--field-copy-title.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--two-column-image-and-copy.html.twig
   * field--field-copy-title.html.twig
   x field--text.html.twig
   * field.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/field/field--text.html.twig' -->

            <div data-quickedit-field-id="paragraph/3/field_copy_title/en/default" class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-copy-title field--type-text field--label-hidden field__item">Copy Title</div>
      
<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/field/field--text.html.twig' -->

</h2>
    

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--paragraph--field-text--two-column-image-and-copy.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--field-text.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--two-column-image-and-copy.html.twig
   * field--field-text.html.twig
   x field--text-long.html.twig
   * field.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/field/field--text-long.html.twig' -->

            <div data-quickedit-field-id="paragraph/3/field_text/en/default" class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-field-text field--type-text-long field--label-hidden field__item"><p>This is copy</p>
</div>
      
<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/field/field--text-long.html.twig' -->


  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
    

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--paragraph--field-image--two-column-image-and-copy.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--field-image.html.twig
   * field--paragraph--two-column-image-and-copy.html.twig
   * field--field-image.html.twig
   * field--entity-reference.html.twig
   x field.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->

            <div data-quickedit-field-id="paragraph/3/field_image/en/default" class="field field--name-field-image field--type-entity-reference field--label-hidden field__item">

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'media' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * media--source-image.html.twig
   * media--image--default.html.twig
   * media--image.html.twig
   * media--default.html.twig
   x media.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/content/media.html.twig' -->
<article data-quickedit-entity-id="media/1" class="contextual-region media media--type-image media--view-mode-default" data-quickedit-entity-instance-id="0">
  <div data-contextual-id="media:media=1:changed=1611767913&amp;langcode=en" data-contextual-token="hqd_klEINY8NCecy3QJtS5pHlPXABV8mh9Ph6EVSa04" class="contextual"><button class="trigger visually-hidden focusable" type="button" aria-pressed="false">Open  configuration options</button>

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'links__contextual' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * links--contextual.html.twig
   x links.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/navigation/links.html.twig' -->
<ul class="contextual-links" hidden=""><li class="entitymediaedit-form"><a href="/media/1/edit?destination=/node/1">Edit</a></li><li class="entitymediadelete-form"><a href="/media/1/delete?destination=/node/1">Delete</a></li></ul>
<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/navigation/links.html.twig' -->

</div>
      

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--media--field-media-image--image.html.twig
   * field--media--field-media-image.html.twig
   * field--media--image.html.twig
   * field--field-media-image.html.twig
   * field--image.html.twig
   x field.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->

  <div data-quickedit-field-id="media/1/field_media_image/en/default" class="field field--name-field-media-image field--type-image field--label-visually_hidden">
    <div class="field__label visually-hidden">Image</div>
              <div class="field__item">

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image_formatter' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->
  

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image_style' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/field/image-style.html.twig' -->


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->
<img src="/sites/devprototype.dd/files/styles/large/public/2021-01/placeimg_500_300_animals.jpg?itok=xuGZ3iBM" width="480" height="288" alt="placeholder" typeof="foaf:Image" class="image-style-large">

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->



<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/field/image-style.html.twig' -->



<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->

</div>
          </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->


  </article>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/content/media.html.twig' -->

</div>
      
<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/classy/templates/field/field.html.twig' -->


  </div>
</div>
<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/bt4ChildTheme/components/two-column-image-and-copy/paragraph--two-column-image-and-copy.html.twig' -->

</div>
          </div>
  
<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/bt4ChildTheme/components/text-field/field--paragraph--section.html.twig' -->


  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I have difficulties understanding the actual issue. What place/component/page in Drupal are you looking at that you want to target for adding helper classes? How is the markup now and how do you need it instead? Note that you often can leave the templates untouched and add classes by preproccessing elements via preprocess hooks like `hook_preprocess_paragraph` or `hook_preprocess_field`. Maybe also have a look at the base theme you are using. They probably had exactly the same issue like you and needed to add lots of Bootstrap classes to the markup. Find out how.

Comment: Note that you also can simply copy templates like `core/themes/classy/templates/field/image-style.html.twig` to your custom themes /templates directory and override the markup there. Maybe also read through some of the articles on https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal. They also will give you lots of info on the overall edge corners of theming in Drupal.

Comment: Turning off twig debug in your services.yml file will get rid of template suggestion lines. And the others are from Quick Link module and Contextual Link module. Logged out users shouldn't see them anyway, but feel free to turn them off too if you want.

Comment: So the quick-edit-field-id div's can't be removed. In the end, I want clean HTML, what is in my twig file is what i want to see, not the extra DIV's and other tags that are getting added.

I am reading through the theming documentation.

Comment: You can make the markup whatever you want.